# ng-controller not working inside a html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-bind-html

Hi I am receiving an HTML response with full angular code embedded in it and I have tried both  ng-bind-html and ng-html-compile for rendering. Neither of it works.The HTML elements are getting rendered properly but none of the ng directives are working. Can anyone please help on this issue?

Inside my controller i am assigning the http response data(html) into a rootscope variable ($rootScope.htmlResponse=data).

this is directive for html compile

```
.directive('ngHtmlCompile', function($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngHtmlCompile, function(newValue, oldValue) {
            element.html(newValue);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        });
    }
};
})
```

searchResults.html:

```
<ion-view  ng-swipe-left="scanClick()">
<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button class="button button-icon button-dark ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left" style="margin-left:-10px;margin-right:-20px" id="lhm_button">
    </button>

</ion-nav-buttons>
<ion-nav-title>
    Product Detail
</ion-nav-title>
<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <button class="button button-icon button-dark ion-search" ng-click="searchIconClick()" style="margin-top:4px;background:#8eb4e3;line-height:5px"></button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
<ion-content>

<div>
    <p **ng-html-compile="htmlResponse"**></p>
</div>
</ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

Here is the sample of the http response i am getting:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>TEST</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.1/angular.min.js">    </script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.1/angular-animate.min.js"></script> 
 </head>
 <body ng-app="myapp">
 <div ng-controller="myController">
  {{name.myname}}
 </div>

 <script>
 var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
 app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
 $scope.name={};
 $scope.name.myname = "stack";
 });

 </script> 
 </body>
 </html>
```

The following result is getting displayed:

```
 {{name.myname}}
```

Comment: Posting some code might help! `ng-app` is in HTML as well?

Comment: yes ng-app, ng-controller ,ng-if everything inside html

Comment: haaaaaa.. @SandeepNayak mean: Please show your code in your  question.

Comment: You may want to manually bootstrap your Angular code to work. Take a look at this: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap (Scroll down to Manual Initialization)

Comment: Please can you post as much of your code as possible to your question so that we can help you with an answer

Comment: @RameshRajendran  sorry,, i am not supposed to share the response,, ;)

Comment: You have removed everything that you say isn't working. Please make a **complete**  example which you have confirmed that it actually replicates the problem. You don't have to use your actual code. Otherwise this is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using iframe....

```
<iframe width="100%" height="500px" ng-attr-srcdoc="{{htmlResponse}}"></iframe>
```

Answer (score -2):

Take this Example code
try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TEST</title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script> 
 </head>
 <body ng-app="myapp">
 <div ng-controller="myController">
   {{name}}
 <mydir rootdata="htmlresponse"></mydir>
 </div>

 <script>
 var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
 app.controller('myController', function ($scope,$rootScope) {
  $scope.name = "stack";
  $rootScope.htmlresponse = "I am root scope";
 });
 app.directive("mydir", function () {
  return {
          restrict : 'E',
          scope    : {
                         da : "=rootdata";
                     }
          template : "<div>Hello I am Directive {{da}}</div>"
         }
 });

 </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The person who asked this question is not aware of syntax.so i given small code snippet

Comment: syntax is not the problem... the html elements are getting rendered properly but the angular components are not getting binded I used both ng-html-compile and ng-bind-html but it is in vain

Comment: @ArepalliPraveenkumar i have edited the question based upon your answer... can yu have a look at it??

Comment: Did you get something you are expecting @sudarshan

Comment: @ArepalliPraveenkumar wat you have given here is working fine...If $rootScope.htmlResponse contains angularjs, then its not working...

Comment: @sudarshan Please do not user camelcase variable in like htmlResponse instead use htmlresponse